# Integration of an equation that looks like inverse tangent

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{1}{1+x^{-2}}dx$$
I thought that this equation would become $$\tan^{-1}(x^{-1})+c$$
What is the proper way to take the integral?

Comment: You're neglecting the chain rule: $\displaystyle\frac d{dx}\tan^{-1}(x^{-1}) = \frac{1}{1+x^{-2}}\cdot\frac d{dx} x^{-1}= \cdots\cdots$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You can do this integral (with the steps) using Sympy Gamma, [here](http://gamma.sympy.org/input/?i=integrate%281%2F%281%2Bx**-2%29%29)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int\frac{dx}{1+x^{-2}} = \int \frac{x^2\,dx}{x^2+1} = \int \left(1-\frac1{x^2+1}\right)dx = x - \arctan(x) + \text{constant}$$

Comment: It could be added that there is a general method that allows one to compute **all** antiderivatives of rational functions (at least, in theory).

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can't assume that if the integrand *looks* like a familiar integral but with some kind of change of variable in place, that you can just take the familiar integral and then substitute. Otherwise I could do stuff like $\int x^2\ dx$ looks like $\int x\ dx$ but with an $x^2$ so it must be $\frac{1}{2}(x^2)^2$.

Instead, rearrange it - user17762 shows a simple way to do so, by noting that $1+x^{-2} = x^{-2}(x^2+1)$ so you can multiply by $x^2/x^2$ to neaten things up.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{1}{1 + {x^{-2}}} \, dx = \int \frac{1}{1 + \frac1{x^2}} \, dx = \int \frac{1}{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}} \, dx = \int \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \, dx = \int \frac{(x^2 + 1) - 1}{x^2+1} \,dx = \int (1 - \frac1{x^2+1}) \, dx =  x - arctan(x) + C $$

It's pretty much the same procedure as posted before this. I just added the hidden step so you know what's happening.

Good luck! C: